# can the webmaster know if I use show page source?

Tags: html

That might be a simple question, but I actually dont know.
Can the owner of a website detect if I hit show source in firefox/chrome?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally, no. It's not possible to tell how the browser has decided to render a page.

*However*, there are a few possible exceptions (though those are largely guesswork):

- If you're using keyboard shortcuts to open it (e.g. Ctrl+U in Firefox), the page could see keypresses with JS. To get around this, use the browser menu (or, in Firefox, just navigate to `view-source:http://example.com`).
- If you're using the right click context menu, the site could override the context menu or possibly gues which item you've clicked depending on how you've moved your mouse. To get around this, use the browser menu (or, in Firefox, just navigate to `view-source:http://example.com`).
- Viewing source of an already loaded page shouldn't trigger an additional request. But viewing source of a not-loaded page would trigger a page request without later subresource loads (e.g. images, script, css), and they could *guess* that this is the cause. Or it could just be a crawler or any number of other bots that randomly hit webpages. Guesswork.

Again, none of these definitively tell the server anything. At best, they can guess, where there's other possible reasons for most of these actions.

That said, no one cares (or should care) if you "view source". It's not some magic hackery.

Comment: simlar to your 3rd dot point: if the page uses javascript to report back user stats to a server (eg. mouse movements) then opening the page with view-source will not do that and the page owner could guess that the page has been opened using a non-interactive method (one possibility is that it was opened with view-source).

Comment: @mulllhausen Yup, though that's all trivially bypassed by simply loading the page as normal before viewing the source of the loaded page. Or even loading the page via a debugging proxy (like Fiddler) that lets you intercept the HTML as it is sent down.